# Why aren't changes in my remote master branch being pulled into my local master branch?

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

I have really been wracking my brain on this. I am using DevOps and the native Visual Studio Team Explorer interface.

1. I created a master branch and pushed it to the remote with.
2. I created a new branch that is also pushed to the remote.
3. I made many changes, updated the remote branch, and merged it into the master.
4. A colleague created a new branch, added some files, pushed it to remote, and merged it into the remote master.
5. The remote master correctly shows the combination of our work.

For the life of my I cannot seem to pull the changes from the origin/remote down to my local master branch.

I have tried Sync, pull, fetch, merge, and rebase.
The local master is bold, indicating it is selected.
I've tried creating new branches and updating just those.
When I am on the syncing menu, there are no incoming commits even though there are changes beyond what is in my local branch.
When I do sync or fetch/merge/pull the menu returns that my local branch is up to date.

I know there is something extremely simple that I'm missing here but after a few hours searching and a Udemy course I am still stumped!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update my question to say that I finally thought to just clone the repository down to a new folder and it revealed some folder pathing issues in the remote master that may have been a part of my problem. I am no longer seeking answer to this question. Thank you to any who considered it!

***edit: It turned out everything was working correctly but my colleague had somehow saved all his project in a subfolder so all the changes were being updated down in that subfolder. Essentially it caused there to be two whole projects in one. I finally got it sorted by copying out changes where they are supposed to go and pushed the correct project up to the remote master.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using correct syntax:
git pull --rebase origin master